# Linear transformations (specially linear forms)

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be an $n$ dimensional vector space. Find all linear forms on it. How do I approach this problem ? If anyone could help.

Answer (score 0):

The set of all linear forms on a vector space $V$ is called as the dual space of $V$, namely $ V^{*} $

The elements of $ V^{*} $ are those that operate on elements of $ V $ and take it to some element of the underlying field.

For example If $ V= \mathbb{R}^{n} $ and the vectors are represented by column matrices, then the elements of  $ V^{*} $ will be row matrices.

Answer (score 0):

The linear forms on $V$ are simply the elements of the vector space $Hom(V, \mathbb{R})$, the so-called dual space $V^*$. Given a basis $\mathcal{B} = \{\mathbf{e}_1,\dots\mathbf{e}_n\}$ of $V$, the dual space $V^*$ is spanned by the dual basis $\mathcal{B}^* = \{\mathbf{e}^1, \dots, \mathbf{e}^n\}$, where, for a vector $x = c_1\mathbf{e}_1 + \dots + c_n\mathbf{e}_n\in V$, $\mathbf{e}^i(\mathbf{x}) = c_i$ for $i = 1,\dots, n$.